# Dual monitors on OSX in vmware workstation

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to run OSX inside vmware workstation 8 and use dual monitors?  For some reason I cannot figure this out and wondering if this is going to be a feature later if it is not already possible.

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: I guess i am looking for any version to work.